# How to get all the values returned from multiprocessing in a tuple in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables

How can we make a tuple of ALL the results created from an "i in range(x) do something" using multiprocessing?

Tried the simple multiprocessing but can't find a way to get the results in one tuple variable.

I'm guessing that multiprocessing for my case, say for creating a tuple of 10000 strings should work faster using multiprocessing than just with the standard code "for i in ragne[x] make a new string and add it..."? For example, if instead of 10000 strings I had to create 10000 string results that needed some heavy CPU work each?

```
import random, string, time, multiprocessing

def randomString(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

def worker(num):
    workdone = randomString(20)
    print("Worker: ", num, "Workdone: ", workdone)
    return # how do I return the workdone string?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    starttime = time.time()

    jobs = []
    Alladdr = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))

        # How do I create a tuple (let's call it Totalworkdone) of all workdone results?

        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    # print()
    # print("All workdone = ", Totalworkdone) # Totalworkdone should be the tuple of ALL the workdone ever created in my loop
    print()
    print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

Hello all. I need to get all the results created from the worker using multiprocessing in one 'big' tuple.

For example, if the "for i in range[20]" makes the worker create 20 random strings, I need to be able to work with a variable Totalworkdone that is a tuple of ALL the strings created by the worker. I don't care if they are in random order, this is fine.

Any help is appreciated but please refrain from URLs pointing to long and confusing code, as I am a newbie trying to do just the above, so I can learn and move forward. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a queue to transfer all the data and than just combine them to a tuple.

```
import random, string, time, multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue

def randomString(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

def worker(num, out_queue):
    workdone = randomString(20)
    print("Worker: ", num, "Workdone: ", workdone)
    out_queue.put(workdone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    starttime = time.time()
    out_queue = Queue()


    jobs = []
    Alladdr = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i, out_queue))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()


    result = []
    for i in range(10):
        val = out_queue.get(block=True) # wait for the next item
        result.append(val)

    for p in jobs:
        p.join() # wait for finish of jobs

    Totalworkdone = tuple(result)


    # print()
    # print("All workdone = ", Totalworkdone) # Totalworkdone should be the tuple of ALL the workdone ever created in my loop
    print()
    print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

Comment: This looks great and simple enough, thank you. I tried to apply it to a different difficulty as far as the worker result is concerned and run it for 10, 50 and worked great, but when I tried it for 100 iterations my Pycharm window froze. I think I managed to run it with 70 or 80. Maybe my fault and I will get back to it tomorrow. after I check what I did wrong if so. Will get back to you.

Comment: It might be that the queue is full. It has a limited length. When it is full, nothing can be added. Your program might block in this case. You have to constantly pull elements from the queue while the jobs are running.

Comment: Thank you Raja. So, if this is the case, how would I pull items while the job is running in your above example? Not sure how to do it, should it be within the (for i in range[100]) or somehow outside the loop?

Comment: You would have to put the "pull"-section of the code in front of the section where you join the threads.

Comment: I have modified my answer to show how to do this. It is a bit easier when you know exactly how many outputs you will get.

Comment: Thank you, RaJa. The new code works without 'hanging' for 100 items, All good here.The funny part, is while the first part
```
for i in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i, out_queue))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

only takes about 4 seconds to complete (for calculating some addresses), the second part
```
result = []
    for i in range(10):
        val = out_queue.get(block=True) # wait for the next item
        result.append(val)

    for p in jobs:
        p.join()
```

Takes another 6 seconds !!!
How can this be?

Comment: (Timings are for 100 items, not 10)  I can't believe that while it works so fast (4 secs) to calculate 100 address using multiprocess, crating the final tuple (results) takes another 6 seconds. This looks too slow

Comment: My code part:
`jobs = []
KeyPairs = Queue()  # max size = limit
for i in range(limit):
 p = Process(target=worker, args=(i, KeyPairs))
 jobs.append(p)
 p.start()

addresses = []
addr2check = []
for i in range(limit):
 val = KeyPairs.get(block=True)  # wait for the next item
 addresses.append(val)
 addr2check = tuple(addr2check) + (val[1],)

for p in jobs:
 p.join()
`

Comment: I can't find the way to post code the right way... I put it between ` but nothing

Comment: Creating the tasks does not take so much time. But the jobs have to to the calculations which takes some time. `output_queue.get(block=True)` waits for elements to become available. It is not adding extra time, just waits for the tasks to end their calculations.